# A RegEx that validates a string starting with a lowercase letter, has no special characters, and has one Capital letter

Tags: javascript, regex

Basically, I need a Javascript RegEx that will ensure a string:

- Starts with a lowercase letter
- Has only ONE uppercase letter in it that isn't at the beginning
- Has no non-alphanumeric characters

It can have numbers, but they can't be at the beginning. Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: Basically, I need $$$. $19/character and I'll even golf the solution for you.

Comment: Basically, what do you have so far? Nothing?

Comment: Why so many down-votes seriously?

Comment: Because it is not well researched. This is a very easy question to google or even search for here on SO. P.S. I didn't even downvote.

Comment: I down voted. Questions lacks effort. He just placed his order and its being fulfilled sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
/^[a-z][a-z0-9]*[A-Z][a-z0-9]*$/
```

It matches a string which starts a lower-case Latin letter, followed by zero or more lower-case Latin letters or decimal digits, followed by a single upper case Latin letter, followed by zero or more lower-case Latin letters or decimal digits. The start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors ensure that no other characters are allowed within the string.

This will work if you mean that it must have *exactly* one upper-case letter. If you mean that it may have *at most* one upper-case letter, simply use a `?` quantifer:

```
/^[a-z][a-z0-9]*[A-Z]?[a-z0-9]*$/
```

Comment: Thank you! I had forgotten to put in the last "zero or more lower-case Latin letters or decimal digits" bit. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:[A-Z][a-z0-9]*)?$
```

This doesn't impose any length limit and would match a single lowercase character (you didn't specify a length limit so I assume that's okay); the uppercase character is not required, but could be made required by removing the `?` at the end.